# Do two equal documents in elasticsearch double the needed disc space

Tags: elasticsearch

When I save the same document for, for example, 10 times, does it need ten times as much disk space? Or are the single fields of the document saved in an index or something and the document only references to this index if more than one document have the same value for one field?

Answer (score 2):

Well answer is yes and no :).
By default the data is stored in a aggregated data structure called lucene reverse index. 
In addition to this , the data that you gave for indexing is also stored in a field called _source. So we can safely assume that the data is stored in two different formats where we can only use reverse index for searching but for retrieving the actual data ,  we need to fetch it from _source. 
So if _source is explicitly disabled , you wont be seeing a linear growth of disk size. ( Given that segment merge is done to a single segment )

If this is not disabled , then the data has to be stored both in _source ( As raw JSON ) and reverse index ( Data is tokenized and then stored )